# SQL how to do day by day itinerary sorting?

Tags: sql

I want to display itinerary day by day for a user. Currently, the data structure is as follows

**ItineraryTable**

```
ID  | Title           | DateFrom   | DateTo    | Order
1   | Easy Jet Flight | 2019-10-01 |2019-10-01 | 1 
2   | Ibis Hotel      | 2019-10-01 |2019-10-10 | 2 
3   | Renting Car     | 2019-10-01 |2019-10-10 | 3 
4   | Air Jet Flight  | 2019-10-10 |2019-10-11 | 4 
5   | Ibis Hotel      | 2019-10-11 |2019-10-18 | 5
4   | Air Jet Flight  | 2019-10-18 |2019-10-18 | 6
```

**Itinerary Expected**

```
ID  | Title           | DateFrom   | DateTo    | Order
1   | Easy Jet Flight | 2019-10-01 |2019-10-01 | 1 
2   | Ibis Hotel      | 2019-10-01 |2019-10-10 | 2 
3   | Renting Car     | 2019-10-01 |2019-10-10 | 3 
2   | Ibis Hotel      | 2019-10-11 |2019-10-11 | 2
2   | Ibis Hotel      | 2019-10-12 |2019-10-13 | 2 
2   | Ibis Hotel      | 2019-10-14 |2019-10-15 | 2 
.......
4   | Air Jet Flight  | 2019-10-10 |2019-10-10 | 4 
5   | Ibis Hotel      | 2019-10-11 |2019-10-12 | 5
5   | Ibis Hotel      | 2019-10-12 |2019-10-13 | 5
5   | Ibis Hotel      | 2019-10-13 |2019-10-14 | 5
5   | Ibis Hotel      | 2019-10-15 |2019-10-16 | 5
5   | Ibis Hotel      | 2019-10-17 |2019-10-18 | 5
....
4   | Air Jet Flight  | 2019-10-18 |2019-10-18 | 6
```

How can I achieve this by sql?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: The sample data doesn't match the expected result.

Comment: im using sql server and the  data is im trying to archive is day by day